# Mozilla Firefox: Select dropdown displays out of browser

Tags: firefox, select, dropdown

If Dropdown is wider and aligned to right the list is shown out of the browser as shown in the image.

Attached reference image for more details

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its because of your `select` value text limit and it can't be handle see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/g832yu6c/).

If you want to handle this you have to decrease your text limit, compare [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/g832yu6c/1/).

why don't you use title with short text ? for example

```
<option value="your value" title="This is my lengthy explanation of what this selection really means, so since you only see 1 on the drop down list you really know that you're opting to elect me as King of Willywarts!  Always be sure to read the fine print!">1</option>
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/g832yu6c/2/)